# Htaccess rewrite issue when redirecting from one dynamic url to another

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am looking to rewrite a URL from current dynamic structure..

`www.domain.com/news/news.php?news=id`

to this new

`www.domain.com/?p=id`

the id is a dynamically number-based id.

I have tried multiple solutions for this, but it seems like I am not good enough at htaccess, because I can't get it to work.

Anyone with a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)news=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/news\.php$ /?p=%1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: ahh. very close to a solution there :)  Thanks.  But for some reason it seems like I am getting this at the end of my new url?  ?news=id  (where id displays the number)

Comment: That should not happen with this rule. Do you have QSA flag by any chance?